# wheaten points (a 19th century or earlier term), what is it?

Tags: meaning

I'm working on a short documentary film on a history topic and use the following text taken from the Russian catalog of World's Columbian Exposition (1893, Chicago) in English:

> *... presented products from a steam flour mill: flour of various sorts, middlings, coarse and fine flour, flour dust and bran, cleaned
> and uncleaned Spring and Winter wheat and **Wheaten points**. The firm
> was founded in 1837.*

The text in Russian is unavalable. The catalog in Russian can only be purchased (history document).
I don't know what are "**wheaten points**". I can't even imagine what it could be, considering the description concerns Russian products. My only guess is ribbons or cords used in dresses as fastening parts (of 16-17th century), they were called points. But it doesn't fit into the context, and I don't think they, the points, could be made of wheat. Maybe there is a typo or a mistake, I don't know. Google search doesn't help. Hope someone helps me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wheaten means "of wheat", but I don't know about the points. A guess based on context is that they may be ears of wheat. Using Google Translate for "wheat ears" gives колосья пшеницы and translating колосья to English gives "spikes". Not really confirmation, but still a possibility.

Comment: It seems like your suggestion is right. Among other meanings wordhippo.com defines point as a tine, which, in its turn, may mean a spike. Also, from what Google search shows, one of the meanings of "wheat tines" is obviously "ears of wheat". What confuses me now is "wheaten", I think "wheat points" would do better here in this case. "Ears of wheat" is what I'll stick to. Thanks!

Comment: @PavelAfonin, yes these days wheaten is a bit old-fashioned.